# How to use class function in Object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I was writing an and to end test in angular. here is the code of page object class.

```
export class AppPage {

NodeArrow(node) {
  let NodeArrow = $$('.toggle-children').get(node);
  return NodeArrow;
  }
}
```

and I was trying to use it from outside of the class.

```
  import { AppPage } from './app.po';
  describe('Interactive component', async () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    page.navigateToEditor();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  });
  let page = await new AppPage();
   it('Deleting item in Paramter tab works', async() => {
       await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.NodeArrow(0)), 10000);
    }
```

but it says NodeArrow is undefined. I am in doubt that whether I have written down the function properly in typescript or not. please let me know what have I done wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor for a class can't return a promise, so you can't `await` it.

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
describe('Interactive component', async () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        page.navigateToEditor();
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    });
    let page = new AppPage(); // No await
    it('Deleting item in Paramter tab works', async () => {
        await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.NodeArrow(0)), 10000);
    }
});
```

If you have async code that need to finish before the object is correctly initialized you can use a static helper function :

```
export class AppPage {
    private constructor() {
        // non async code 
    }

    static async create() : Promise<AppPage> {
        var r = new AppPage();
        await r.asynInit()
        return r
    }
    async asynInit() : Promise {
        // async cod
        await delay(100);
    }
    NodeArrow(node) {
        let NodeArrow = $$('.toggle-children').get(node);
        return NodeArrow;
    }
}

import { AppPage } from './app.po';
describe('Interactive component', async () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        page.navigateToEditor();
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    });
    let page = await AppPage.create();
    it('Deleting item in Paramter tab works', async () => {
        await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.NodeArrow(0)), 10000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `await` from your `new AppPage()`

```
import {
  AppPage
} from './app.po';

describe('Interactive component', async () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    page.navigateToEditor();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  });
  let page = new AppPage(); // remove await
  it('Deleting item in Paramter tab works', async () => {
    await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.NodeArrow(0)), 10000);
  })
});
```